# Filtering SQL data into multiple DataTables in a single DataSet

Tags: vb.net, dataset

This should be simple, but it's escaping me right now as I have not written in VB in over a decade.
I have a stored procedure that gets a list of students and their assigned homeroom teacher.
Very basic - just the three columns: `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Teacher`.

What I need is to load the data into a DataSet where each `Teacher` has their own DataTable filled with the students assigned to them.

Sample data:

[image: Sample data]

So in the example above, I would end up with 3 DataTables named `Adams`, `Taggert` and `Dublin`, each populated with the students associated with them all in a single DataSet in such a way that I could call the data with:

```
For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables("Taggert").Rows
    ' Do something with dr("FirstName").ToString
Next
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need to do that?  Depending on the end game, it would seem to make more sense to me to not have any `DataSet` at all and just populate one `DataTable` with all the data, then create three `DataViews` on that one `DataTable`, each filtering by a different `Teacher` value.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I agree that there are a number of better ways, but I was handed a project that has already been in place for a number of years and told to "Fix it". I was trying to make as few changes as possible. The old code basically retrieved a list of teachers, and looped through each of them calling another stored procedure over and over again adding the new tables as it went. This stopped working when access to the teachers list went away. So I'm trying to accomplish the same end result by retrieving one list, and parsing it on the fly so the rest of the program continues to work.

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately used elements from both answers to find a solution. I ended up using DataViews to create the tables, and added them into the new DataSet. It works perfectly. It iterates through every record, but for the few hundred students it handles, it's actually quite 
 efficient. Thanks for the comments.

```
            For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                Dim Teacher As String = row("Teacher").ToString()

                If Not dsOutput.Tables.Contains(Teacher) Then
                    Dim dvStudents = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
                    dvStudents.RowFilter = "Teacher = '" & Teacher & "'"
                    Dim subTable As New DataTable(Teacher)
                    subTable = dvStudents.ToTable(Teacher)
                    dsOutput.Tables.Add(subTable)
                End If
            Next
```

Answer (score -1):

old_datatable with all teachers , i will declare this but you use your own

```
    Dim old_datatable As New DataTable
    Dim new_dataset As New DataSet
    For Each row As DataRow In old_datatable.Rows
        Dim teacher As String = row("Teacher")
        If new_dataset.Tables.Contains(teacher) = False Then
            Dim new_datatable As New DataTable
            new_dataset.Tables.Add(new_datatable)
        End If
        new_dataset.Tables(teacher).Rows.Add(row)
    Next

    For Each dr As DataRow In new_dataset.Tables("Taggert").Rows
        ' Do something with dr("FirstName").ToString
    Next
```